# check if I have a value in a column for a unique identifier

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table in which I have this information :

[image]

I want to have this result by a calculated column or measure dax.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What's your problem with explaining the logic behind this transformation and where do these ID = 3 columns suddenly come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution. Try it out, it solves your question!

[image]

Comment: I don’t have only 1 2 3… 1A, AT…

Comment: So ID < 3 doesn’t work

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What's the general rule? After all it results in your expected table, see your question.

Comment: I have AD, ZE, TR… as ID

Comment: I'm getting curious. How is this relevant for the solution? As always, posting your sample data would help.